# How to preserve the value of variable and display it next time when I open my web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a variable in my ASP.NET Web application which has a default value initially and changes when the application proceeds. I want to display the latest updated value of the variable (i.e. in a label field)the next time when I open my application. I am thinking of storing the value in database and display the last stored value. But is there any other easy and effective way to do that? I am pretty new to .NET and any help is appreciable

Comment: Database is pretty much the only way to have the value persist across all users.  You can persist a user-specific value using a cookie if you're OK with storing it on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

Using a database to store a single value is like using a tank to kill a fly. The simplest way is keeping the value in the `Application` collection, but it will not be saved if you web server is restarted. You might want to use a simple text file if it's only a single value. You can use `File.ReadAllText()` and `File.WriteAllText()` to read and write text to a file on your server.